# File:// link doing nothing in all browsers

Tags: html, file, iframe, uri, href

I have a link being generated that looks like so:

```
<a target="_blank" title="Test" href="file:///c:/test.xls">Test</a>
```

This link is inside an iframe.

When I click on it (in any major browser), *nothing* happens.  Fiddler records no traffic.
Pasting the URL into the nav bar works fine - the file download box comes up, and I can download the file no problem.

I've tried every variant of the URL structure (correct and incorrect, colons, slashes, backslashes, etc.) that I can think of.

I'm certain that it's some kind of security restriction, but I can't for the life of me find out what it is or how to get around it.  I'm feeling pretty foolish at this point.  Any simple explanations?

Comment: You won't see traffic in Fiddler because Fiddler is a HTTP/HTTPS debugger. IE blocks access to local machine zone files from the Internet; other browsers block all File:// access from non-file:// pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, if you are pulling this page off of a server  (acessing it as http://), the security settings won't let you link to local content (acess links as file://). I've had this same problem accessing shared .doc files in a wiki. Never came up with a good solution.

Comment: I figured it was something like this.  I don't suppose you have any documentation links about this?  My googling mojo is terrible today...

Comment: There is no way to remotely get around this restriction. Any way to do so would be treated as a security hole and patched.

Comment: Yeah I understand completely, I'm just looking for some documentation to hand to the client to say why this won't work for them ;)

Comment: In Chrome/Firefox, hit CTRL+SHIFT+J and their debuggers will show a useful error message (Access Denied)

Answer (score 0):

Try a colon instead of a pipe ;)

Comment: Doesn't work.  I've tried every variant of colons and slashes and pipes that I can think of.